# Are two marginal distributions of a student-t copula equivalent to using two independent uniform distributions?

Tags: uniform-distribution, sas, copula, marginal-distribution

I am trying to figure out if these two are the same:

1. Using the marginal uniform distributions of a student-t copula
2. Using independent uniform distributions

I have generated SAS code to figure this out below... and largely my results look correct. Is there any reason the marginal uniforms of a copula would be different to two independent uniforms?

```
/*
Proving that a RANUNI creates similar results to a PROC COPULA with an identity matrix.
*/

data uni1;
 DO i=1 to 10000;
 S1=RANUNI(1234);
 OUTPUT;
 END;
RUN;

data uni2;
 DO i=1 to 10000;
 S2=RANUNI(2345);
 OUTPUT;
 END;
RUN;

data uni_merged;
merge uni1 uni2;
run;


TITLE "RANUNI";
PROC SGPLOT DATA=uni_merged;
HISTOGRAM S1;
DENSITY S1 / TYPE=normal; 
XAXIS LABEL='Simulated Samples (RANUNI)';
run;
title;

Proc corr data=uni_merged;
   var s1 s2;
run;

data corr_matrix;
length Name $ 2 S1 8 S2 8;
Infile datalines delimiter=",";
input Name S1 S2;
datalines;
S1,1,0
S2,0,1
;run;

proc copula;
   var s1-s2;
   define cop t (DF=10 corr=corr_matrix);
   simulate cop / ndraws     = 10000
                  seed       = 1234
                  outuniform = copula;
run;

TITLE "PROC COPULA";
PROC SGPLOT DATA=copula;
HISTOGRAM S1;
DENSITY S1 / TYPE=Normal ; 
XAXIS LABEL='Simulated Samples (Copula)';
run;
title;

proc corr data=copula;
   var s1 s2;
run;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "using"?  In what way, exactly?  (Please don't refer to the code: explain your question in English.)

Comment: @whuber I want to model two severe events that could be related (e.g. server failure and flood risk). I need two versions - one where there is no correlation between them, and another where there is. These are starting uniforms that I then convert to other distributions. 

The correlated version can be achieved using a copula with a correlation matrix. 

For the non-correlated one, I am using a copula with an identity matrix. 

But then I thought, could I just use two random uniform distributions for the uncorrelated scenarios as my starting distributions?

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent approaches, assuming by "non-correlated" you mean *independent.*  (There are uncorrelated, non-independent distributions with uniform marginals.  For instance, let $U$ have a uniform distribution.  Choose randomly, with equal probabilities, from the two ordered pairs $(U,U)$ and $(U,1-U).$  Call that value $(X,Y).$ Then both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and their correlation is zero, but obviously they are not independent because either $X+Y=1$ or $X-Y=0.$)